# Why mousewheel event is not working some times with my code?

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to make a fullpage component in Angular :
I want each sections take a 100% height of my screen, and when I scroll in a section (up or down) it goes to the next / previous section. I declared this function to do that, and it works :

```
@HostListener('wheel', ['$event'])
    onScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
        if (event.deltaY < 0) {
            this.slidePrev();
        } else {
            this.slideNext();
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to update a little to slide to the previous slide only if the scrollbar is on the top, or slide to the next only if the scrollbar is to the bottom. I Used JQuery to do that, this way :

```
@HostListener('mousewheel', ['$event'])
    onScroll(event: WheelEvent) {
        if (this.isSliding) {
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }
        let $section = $(event.target).closest(".section");
        //$section.css("opacity", "0.99");
        //setTimeout(() => {
        //  $section.css("opacity", "1");
        //}, 100);

        if (event.deltaY < 0) {
            if ($section.scrollTop() == 0) this.slidePrev();
        } else {
            if ($section.scrollTop() == $section.prop("scrollHeight") - $section.height()) this.slideNext();
        }
    }
```

It works the first time, but if I slide down to the next slide, when I want to sroll to move my scrollbar, it doesn't move.
I noticed that after the website trigger an update (example : css :hover event that update style) the scrollbar move again. So, if I uncomment my 4 commented lines, it works again because the style is updated.
Can someone tell me why ? And is there a better way to fix that issue ?

**EDIT :**

in slideNext() and slidePrev() I'm using $().animate("scrollTop", ...) function, and it's the function that breaks my scroll

Comment: I already try scroll, and the event is never fired (no console log in the console)

Comment: Yes, but the event is not fired at all.. I just updated the "mousewheel" to "wheel", because "mousewheel" is not working on Firefox